# the effects of single SNPs or the single SNPs effects?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles

I am wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct?

> Predicting genomic breeding values by using methods that rely on the estimation of the effects of haplotype blocks (i.e., a set of at least two neighboring SNPs are presumably transmitted together across generations may result in more accurate evaluations compared to doing genomic predictions by using methods that rely on the estimation of **the effects of single SNPs**.

Comment: So far I don't see a sentence there. It feels like it wants to be a sentence, but right now it hasn't accomplished that goal and just looks like an assortment of clauses all competing with each other for preeminence. On top of that, the subject matter is sufficiently dense and specialized that your best bet is to get a scientific colleague to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Predicting genomic breeding values by using methods that rely on the estimation of the effects of haplotype blocks (i.e., a set of at least two neighboring **SNPs [which are] presumably transmitted together** across generations **)** may result in more accurate evaluations compared to doing genomic predictions by using methods that rely on the estimation of the effects of single SNPs.

There is nothing wrong with the part about "single SNPs:" it's grammatical, and the meaning is clear. But, it may be even clearer to say "individual SNPs."

However, in bold I marked two other areas with mistakes. One is a forgotten paren/bracket ( ). The other is grammatical. "SNPs are transmitted together..." is ungrammatical here. What you want is the relative clause "SNPs which are transmitted together" or the easier-to-read "SNPs transmitted together" (you can choose to omit "which are").

Comment: very useful comments!

Answer (score 1):

> Predicting genomic breeding values by using methods that rely on the
>   estimation of the effects of haplotype blocks (i.e., a set of at least
>   two neighboring SNPs), that are presumably transmitted together across
>   generations, may result in more accurate evaluations compared to doing
>   genomic predictions by using methods that rely on the estimation of
>   the effects of single SNPs.

How about this? I turned the **that are presumably transmitted together across generations** part into an appositive, providing some clarity.
As for the part about "effects of single SNPs or the single SNPs effects, this depends on the message you are trying to convey. Are you talking about one specific single SNP? In that case you would use **the single SNPs effects**. If you are talking about *ALL* single SNPs, you would use **the effects of single SNPs**.

**Note that this may be better edited by someone who understands the subject of the sentence.**

Comment: Actually, you should be able to deduce the proper placement of the closed paren just from the grammar of the contents. Same for the other issues. But if ever you were unsure, that's what Google is for: "Several neighboring, tightly linked SNPs are inherited together and form a haplotype block, which as a haploblock has a higher discrimination power than the individual SNPs within the block." (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20033199)

Comment: I believe I did get the correct close parens and commas.